# Best practice for the order of function arguments in Python

Tags: python

I often write functions that take one argument with data to be manipulated, and one or more additional arguments with specifications for the manipulation. If the "specification" parameters are optional, it makes sense to place them after the obligatory `data` argument:

```
sort(data, key=..., reverse=True)
```

But suppose both arguments (or several of them) are obligatory? The functions of the `re` module place the regexp (the manipulation) before the string (the data to be manipulated). Optional arguments still come last, of course.

```
re.search(r"[regexp]+", text, flags=re.I)
```

So here's the question: Putting optional arguments aside, are there any clear conventions (official PEP or *established* common practice) for how to order obligatory arguments based on their function/purpose? Back when I was first learning Python, I  remember reading some claim to the effect that one of Python's advantages is that it has clear conventions, inter alia on this particular thing. But I am unable to retrieve any such information now.

In case it is not clear: I am kindly asking for pointers to established conventions or standards, not for advice on which order is "best."

Comment: I'm pretty sure PEP 8 doesn't address this. I suppose, this is similar to the way `map(f, data)` and `filter` work... to me, the most important thing is to maintain consistency in your API

Comment: It doesn't, I checked before I wrote this question :-)

Comment: agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga establish your own convention, and be consistent with it

Comment: So I guess in your opinion(s) the two orders are equally good? I already have a convention, but I want to know what wiser heads, and community wisdom, have concluded.

Comment: Found this article (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314818) with some slightly relevant information, but I think that in the vast majority of cases, the above comments are correct in that consistency is the main issue for argument order. I couldn't find a standard specific to the issue. The article mostly covers more fringe cases in addition to optional arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too. But it doesn't say anything about ordering required arguments, does it?

Answer (score 0):

This is one hell of a good question and I'm already excited to see other answers. I've never come across any conventions about functions arguments in Python except in PEP 8 where it states that:

> Always use self for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use cls for the first argument to class methods.
>
> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is
>   generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than
>   use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus class_ is better than
>   clss. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

In my opinion, functions parameter should always be in order of importance. I know *importance* is subjective but you generally can determine which of the parameters is the most important to your function. Since StackOverflow is not about opinion take this with a grain of salt.

So putting aside opinions, I think your question is relevant but sometimes questions leads to other discussions. If you have numerous parameters, your function is probably doing too much stuff. According to a lot of ressources, you should try to use only one parameter and avoid using more than three where the latter is considered as the worst case scenario. So, most of the time ordering parameters won't impact readability that much if you keep that in mind.

Comment: I find it amusing that the parameter in rule 2 is supposed to be called `cls` rather than `class_`, violating rule 3.

Answer (score 0):

I try to order parameters to help code readability (literate programming).
ex:

```
  system.add(user, user_database) # add a user to a database
  system.add(user_database, user) # add a database to a user(?)
```

This usually coincide with @scharette's opinion, the "most important" parameter is the object for which the function was created for. But as (he) stated  it's subjective, it could be argued the database is the most important object in a database system library.

Reading code should reveal intent on first read; reading a set of function definitions should reveal what they do.